Talkback is reading hidden elements in Android
I am developing a app where there is single activity and all the webviews/fragment load in ti only and based on criterias or screen few of the elements are hidden or visible.
When i enable talkback it is reading the hidden elements on the screen.
I want talkback to read it only when those elements are visible. like toolbar items, bottom nav item. It should not read those items on login screen.
